# Decoding of DVB PSI

Tags: c++, vlc, dvb

We are looking for a project that can decode DVB PSI sections. We have had a look into libdvbpsi but it only seems to handle the raw transport packets. In our application the data we are being sent has all the transport information already removed and the section assembled. Our code base is also C++, so if there is a C++ project, then this would be more beneficial but we are not against using a C one.

Is there a way of getting libdvbpsi to work just with sections?
or
Is there any other project out there that do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this documentation here: 
http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvbpsi/doc/doxygen/html/structure.html

Basically, libdvbpsi has two levels, the `PSI Decoder` and `Specific Decoder`

The `PSI Decoder` is what Application uses to pass on all TS data i.e. 188 bytes format. The PSI decoder in turn depacketizes and collects the full Sections. Second thing is that it knows which chunk has which corresponding tables in it - and invokes respective `Specific Decoder`.

In your application, if you have already stripped TS data and also gathered appropriate sections together, then you can bypass `PSI decoder` and directly call the `Specific decoders`.

Comment: Thanks, however, the psi decoders need 188 byte packets and our incoming data has already formed the section.

Comment: @user626201 i understood your point which is why you should *BYPASS* psi decoder! Directly CALL specific decoder which is PAT Decoder - read the answer fully!